IOS app crashed after API calling in expo
My Expo App crashed in IOS device, Below is the code
I think it is beacause of AbortController and API call, can please anyone help in this?
useEffect(() => {
        loadConfig(abortController)
        return () => {
            abortController.abort()
        }
    }, [])

const abortController = new AbortController()

const loadConfig = useCallback(async (abortController : any) => {
        try {
            let api_data = {} as configData
            
            if(globals.org_id != undefined){
                api_data.org_id = globals.org_id
            }else {
                let uData = await getUserData() as UData
                api_data.org_id = uData.org_id
            }
            
            if(globals.selectedLevel != undefined){
                api_data.lid = [globals.selectedLevel]
            }else{
                api_data.lid = [await getLevels() as string]
            }
            
            api_data.mac_id = [data.mac_id]
            api_data.config_type = "config"
            
            console.log(api_data,"--------------------------------->")
            console.log(abortController,"****************************************")
            
            let config_data = await getConfigData(api_data, abortController)

            console.log(config_data,"config_dataconfig_dataconfig_dataconfig_data")
            
            if(config_data.data.statusCode === 200){
                let latest_config = config_data.data.result[0].latest_config
                let old_config = config_data.data.result[0].old_config
                for(let oc of object_config){
                    if(latest_config[oc] != undefined && latest_config[oc][oc] != undefined){
                        latest_config[oc] = latest_config[oc][oc]
                    }
                    if(old_config && old_config[oc] != undefined && old_config[oc][oc] != undefined){
                        old_config[oc] = old_config[oc][oc]
                    }
                }
                
                setConfigData((prevState) => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    new_config: latest_config,
                    old_config: old_config,
                    prev_new_config: latest_config
                }))
            }else{
                ShowToast({id: "error_config", status: "error", title: "Error", description: "Error"})
        }
            
        } catch (error: any) {

            console.log(error,"Errorrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr")
            ErrorHandling(error)
        }
    }, [])

//In this before this line app get crashed

let config_data = await getConfigData(api_data, abortController)


const getConfigData = (data: configData, abortController: AbortController) => {
        return authAxios.post('panel/configs/get_new', data, {signal: abortController.signal})
    } 

It is consoling till
console.log(api_data,"--------------------------------->")
console.log(abortController,"****************************************")
Problem is that every time when controller.abort() is called the app crash without any error.
How to fix it?
